# Javascript style guide variable declarations

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know why on the airbnb style guide this one is bad, while the other one is good? I would expect the 'name' variable to hoisted, like the previous example.

thanks in advance.

Here's a link.
https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#variables

```
// bad
function() {
  var name = getName();

  if (!arguments.length) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

// good
function() {
  if (!arguments.length) {
    return false;
  }

  var name = getName();

  return true;
}
```

Comment: Because you don't need the variable if there are no arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if `!arguments.length` is `true`, you don't want to execute the rest of the function anyway, so there's no point in calling the function `getName();` when assigning the variable that you'd never use when `!arguments.length`.

Comment: But technically does the variable declaration get hoisted before the condition? Just that the initialization never happens?